# How to use Java 8 with Lib GDX in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, ide

I have set the jdk to Java 8 and I have modified all the build.gradle files in my project to have sourceCompatibility = 1.8 instead of 1.6. My problem is that while it does work on Desktop it doesn't when I run it on Android. Can someone tell me how to properly set up the project to use Java 8 so that it works on all platforms in IntelliJ?

Comment: Do you mean that it works for older version of java, but doesn't for java 8 ?

Comment: Yeah, when java source = 1.6 it works on both android and desktop but when java source = 1.8 it works on desktop but on android it gives an error relating to DexDebug I remember.

Comment: Just to mention, the variable inside the build.gradle was called sourceCompatibility not java source. Still the problem remains the same, if I change that variable to 1.8 it runs on desktop but not on android.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Apparently Android does not support Java 8 yet, but you can use lambda expressions in Android. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development/28394024#28394024) to a page with a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Android supports all Java 7 language features and a subset of Java 8 language features that vary by platform version. To enable those features add this to your build.gradle:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

To read more about Java 8 and Jack Toolchain in Android go to this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html).

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio in version > 3.0.0 natively supports some Java 8 features.

In Android Studio, go to File > Project structure > select android > Tab properties > Source compatibility > 1.8.

You will also need to set the target compatibility to 1.7 (yes, 1.7 because there is some conversion process involved to translate Java 8 features to be compatible with Java 7 native code)